# Как проверить отозван сертификат или нет?

Tags: openssl, pem, certificate

Допустим.

```
echo | openssl s_client -connect dns.google:443 | openssl x509 -certopt ca_default -out googledns.pem -outform PEM
```

Как теперь проверить googledns.pem? С каким CRL списком сравнивать?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно запросить OSCP сервер удостоверяющего центра о статусе сертификата.

1. Узнать URL сервера `openssl x509 -noout -ocsp_uri -in googledns.pem`

   Результат: http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1o1core
2. Получить сертификат удостоверяющего центра:

   `openssl x509 -text -noout -in googledns.pem | grep -i issuer`

   Результат: ссылка http://pki.goog/gsr2/GTS1O1.crt

   Скачать сертификат CA и преобразовать его из DER в PEM:

```
wget http://pki.goog/gsr2/GTS1O1.crt
openssl x509 -in GTS1O1.crt -inform DER -out issuer.pem -outform PEM
```

3. Запросить OSCP сервер: `openssl ocsp -issuer issuer.pem -cert googledns.pem -text -url http://ocsp.pki.goog/gts1o1core`

   Результат:

```
Response verify OK
googledns.pem: good
```